# How to subclass a Singleton in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I'm trying to subclass a class that uses singleton pattern and populate the instance with the subclass.

I seem to be having a little trouble.

```
class Singleton {

    static private $instance;

    static public function instance(){
        if(is_null(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct(){}

}

class MySingleton extends Singleton {

}

echo get_class(MySingleton::instance()); //=> Singleton

//=> I'm hoping to see MySingleton
```

Comment: What is the trouble, what doesn't work?

Comment: @Pekka, I want the class to be `MySingleton` (as noted in the comment), not `Singleton`;

Comment: @Pekka his question is hiding as comments at the bottom :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) which is a new feature of PHP 5.3. Try replacing `new self()` with `new static()` and this should work for you.

`self` always references the containing class, whereas `static` references the "called" class.

Comment: that won't work if he also wants to keep the ability to use Singleton on its own.

Comment: Whoa I consider myself a PHP enthusiast and I was unaware of this..Then again I'm still using 5.2.x haha This is fantastic!!

Comment: Never consider yourself expert in programming ;)

Comment: @Kris What do you mean? The only thing I see preventing the direct usage of the singleton class is the protected constructor.

Comment: @John: the field `static $instance` will hold an instance of whatever `Singleton` type gets called first this way, which might not be the requirement. Note that i'm not saying this is wrong for the purpose of this question, just that it could not work as expected under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Your singleton base class prevents that as is. if you change the code to this though, it will work.

```
<?php


class Singleton {

    static private $instances = array();

    static public function instance(){
        $class = get_called_class();
        if(!isset(self::$instances[$class])){
            self::$instances[$class] = new $class();
        }
        return self::$instances[$class];
    }

    private function __construct(){}

}

class MySingleton extends Singleton {

}

echo get_class(MySingleton::instance()); //=> MySingleton
```

Now it works because Singleton allows for one instance per child class.

Comment: I just want to prevent people from modifying the parent class.  The app will still access the singleton using the parent class, but i want developers to be able to overwrite any functionality in the subclass.  Can you think of any reason I'd need to maintain a separate instance of the parent class?

Comment: That depends wholly on what you are using it for. but the other solution will blow up if somewhere in your code there is Singleton::instance() before MySingleton::instance() because it will always only have an instance of whichever got called first.

Comment: Kris, thanks for the heads-up.  I am aware that `MySingleton::instance()` needs to be called first.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
<?php

class Singleton {

    static private $instance;
    static public function instance(){
        static $instance = null;  
        return $instance ?: $instance = new static;
    }

    public function __construct(){}

}

class MySingleton extends Singleton {
}
```

But i recommend the following one:

```
<?php
class Singleton {

    static protected $instance;              //should not be private

    static public function instance(){
        if(is_null(static::$instance)){         
            static::$instance = new static();
        }
        return static::$instance;

    }

    public function __construct(){}

}

class MySingleton extends Singleton {
    static protected $instance;    //must explicitly declared
}
```